# Preserve at least one P element inside contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable with a `<p>` element inside it like the following

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        dummy content here !!!!! 
    </p>
</div>
```

When I click backspace on the keybord until it remove all the text, if I click the backspace again it removes also the `<p>` element ! In my case I would like to keep at least one `<p>` element there

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e){

    var contenteditable = $(this)

    if(e.keyCode == 8){ // if backspace

        var p = contenteditable.find('p');

        var pLength = p.length;

        if(pLength == 1){ // if only one <p> exists inside contenteditable

            var pHtml = p.html();

            // if only <br> is still inside <p> then prevent
            // the backspace to delete the <p>
            if( pHtml == "<br>" || pHtml == ""){

                e.preventDefault()

            }
        }

    }
});
```

But it doesn't work ! **also I want to prevent the deletion of `<p>` if the user select the whole text at once using Ctrl+A or the mouse and hits the Backspace key.**

I am also not sure if my method is the best way to go, but I am open to all suggestions ! thanks

**UPDATE :**

I've found another way to do it but still not complete :

```
$(document).on('keyup', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e){

    var contenteditable = $(this);

    if( e.keyCode == 8 ) {

        if(contenteditable.find('p').length == 0){

            contenteditable.html('<p><br></p>');

        }
    }

});
```

on Backspace keydown I check if no P element exists inside the contenteditable, if no element found I add one with `<br>` inside, but still need to set the caret before the br

Comment: Would use a wysiwyg editor script myself. Different browsers use different html in contenteditable

Comment: It's work, what is the problem? in my case the <p> element not is removed https://jsfiddle.net/pLrk1vrf/1/

Comment: @CMedina doesn't work in firefox for me !! also I am not sure about IE

Comment: Try please https://jsfiddle.net/pLrk1vrf/2/ its working for me in mozilla

Comment: @CMedina select all the text using Ctrl+A and remove, you will see that the p is removed as well

Comment: @CMedina what do you think about the updated method in my question? I have found a way to set the cursor before the br but only for standar browsers not IE, if you want I can post the code, but need to translate it for IE as well

Comment: Sorry, I don't have IE in my pc:/