# Set the caret at a specific point in a dynamically added HTML

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a contenteditable div

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable"></div>
```

I append some html to it using :

```
$('.editable').html('<p><br></p>');
```

How I can set the caret before `<br>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting cursor position in content editables is tricky business. 
The handling of cursor is browser dependent.
There are range and selection apis which are quite inconsistent over different browsers.

*This is how to play with cursors:*

Create a range object by `document.createRange()`
select the specified position by range methods (see the api)
Get selection object by `selection=window.getSelection()`
remove all existing selection by `selection.removeAllRanges();`
add the range to the selection by `selection.addRange(range);`

In this situations there is no text content in paragraph element, so you cannot place cursor inside it. You can either select the node by `range.selectNode` or you can place the cursor before/after the element.
Placing the cursor before or after will also behave weirdly in different browsers especially in edge cases (like in empty `div` or first or last postion).

You have to clearly specify what you want to achieve in the UI. Then I can suggest some logic to accomplish that.

Comment: concerning the logic I want to accomplish, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365253/preserve-at-leaste-one-p-element-inside-contenteditable?noredirect=1#comment62245775_37365253